# Ember Data not loading hasMany on store.find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I currently have a model with two hasMany relationships as seen below:

**Ember Model:**

```
DS.Model.extend({
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  zip: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('user',{async:true}),
  templates: DS.hasMany('template',{async:true})
});
```

Using this model, I have new templates/controllers/etc setup to create new users and new templates.  I can successfully save new/update existing organizations, but when I try to push objects into either users or templates, I lose what may already be in the other of the existing users or templates array.

I can see this is because my loading of the organization in the controller to create new records is not pulling in the other records, it pulls in it's own array, but not the other, for example this code on the new templates controller:

**New Template Controller**

```
  organizations: function(){
    return this.store.find('organization');
  }.property(),
  actions: {
    createTemplate: function() {
      var self = this;
      console.log(self.get('organizations'));
    }
  }
```

Will show the templates in the console when attached to the record, but not the users.  Vise versa, the same code on the new users controller does not show the templates it is pulling in but does show the users.

What can I do to get my find to return both arrays of relationships.  They are both in the database, I can see them calling the rest api, but just not when they are found using ember.

I'm still pretty new with Ember, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Sample JSON response from server

```
{
  "organization": {
     "id": 40,
     "name": "Sample Business LLC",
     "address": "1234 Fun Avenue",
     "city": "Happytown",
     "state": "NE",
     "zip": "12345",
     "users": [4,1],
     "templates": [4,1],
     "createdAt": "2014-02-18T23:10:08.466Z",
     "updatedAt": "2014-02-18T23:10:08.466Z"}
   },
   "meta": {
     "href": "http://server/organizations/40"
   }
}
```

Comment: would you mind including the json returned from the organization endpoint?

Comment: See edit above for the json from the endpoint.

Comment: Is your `organization` object really a var like that? Because Ember-Data expects it to exist in your application namespace.

Comment: Sorry no, I'm actually using ember app kit, so I actually just export the organization out and it's added to the namespace.  I removed that out of the question.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but I'm having the same issue. Did you figured it out by any chance?